How does Linear and Exponential Fog work in Unity URP?
I am a novice in Unity, I see that volumetric fog is not available when using the URP and the recommended method is to use Linear or Exponential Fog.
I played around with it a little. Even though including it in the scene was straightforward. I have a few questions:

Are both of these fogs implemented in screen-space as a post-process effect?
If not, are the fog calculations somehow injected into the fragment shader of our custom material when it is compiled to HLSL?

